# "your website/app should contain these pages" facing in razor pay verification in app

Tags: razor, payment-gateway, razorpay, flutter-razorpay, razorpay-andoid-sdk

"your website/app should contain these pages"
Facing above issue when submit app for live review in razor pay.

I submitted app screenshots as per guidance of razor pay site.

Also explained in screenshot how to follow that payment flow will work